# iterating over list to increment by 'x' and create new list

Tags: python, list, iteration

Am a python beginner and trying to build a simple cipher where I iterate over one list and then increment by 3 to build a new list but keep getting a type error.
lower_list = list from abcd.....z

And when I execute following get a type error:

```
    for i in lower_list:
        shift_lower += lower_list[i:i+3]
```

Anyone offer any tips on how this might be done syntactically correct? thanks.

Comment: Could you be clearer on what you want the resultant list to be? Maybe an example?

Comment: @marv77 do you shift the characters by 3? As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Comment: `i`, according to your definition of `lower_list = "abcd...xyz"` is a string, and you can't index `lower_list` with a string, or add 3 to it. It looks like you want `for i in range(len(lower_list)): etc.`

Comment: `i` may not be an int, and even if it is you will probably get index out of bounds exception. Try `for i in range(len(lower_list))`

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback - was able to achieve most of what I wanted with @Ch3steR solution however stuck trying to wrap around such that when the shift exceeds 'z' it wraps back again and starts at 'a'. Tried below :

lower_list = [<a list of a....z>]
cipher_lower = []
shift = 4
shift_unicode = 0

for i in lower_list:
    cipher_lower += [chr(ord(i) + shift)]
    shift_unicode = (ord(i) + shift)
    if shift_unicode > 122:
            cipher_lower += [chr(ord(i) - 26)]

But no luck - list statement does seem to work ??? Any tips would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try this.

```
lower_list=['a','b',...,'z']
cipher_text=[chr(ord(i)+3) for i in lower_list]
```

---

```
['d',
 'e',
 'f',
 ...
 'z',
 '{',
 '|',
 '}']
```

---

**EDIT:**

When domain and range of characters is `a-z`(for brevity I'm considering lower case a-z). This is an example of *Caeser Cipher*.

```
C.T=(P.T+K)Mod26
```

Implementation:

```
lower_list=['a', 'b' ,'c', ..., 'z']
cipher_text=[chr((ord(s) + incr - 97) % 26 + 97)  for s in lst]
```

You can build a function to handle both encryption and decryption. I would do it this way.

```
def caeser_cipher(lst,incr,encrypt=True):
    if encrypt:
        return [chr((ord(s) + incr - 97) % 26 + 97)  for s in lst]
    else:
        return [chr((ord(s) - incr - 97) % 26 + 97)  for s in lst]
```

---

```
lower_letters=['a','b', ...'z']
cipher_text=caeser_cipher(lower_letters,4)
#['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', ... ,'c', 'd']
plain_text=caeser_cipher(cipher_text,4,encrypt=False)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', ...,'z']
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ch3steR - this did it! Also thanks others for suggestions and will remember for next time to be clearer with posts.

Comment: @marv77 Glad to help. If this helped please accept this as answer and upvote. ;)

Comment: Hi, I need the resultant cipher_text to 'wrap' around and restart at a,b, c  when it gets to x, y and z. I tried doing this using IF statements but unsuccessful. For eg.
        for i in self.lower_list:
            self.cipher_lower += [chr(ord(i) + shift)]
            if i == [x]:
                self.cipher_lower = [a]
            elif i == [y]:
                self.cipher_lower = [b]
            elif i == [z]:
                self.cipher_lower = [c]

But no luck. Also I want it to skip any non-alphcharacters. Thank you

Comment: @marv77 check the edited answer. Feel free to ask if you have any doubts in the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase


def encode(original_text: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(
        ascii_lowercase[(ascii_lowercase.index(c) + 3) % len(ascii_lowercase)]
        if c in ascii_lowercase else c
        for c in original_text
    )


print(encode('test xyz'))
```

output:

```
whvw abc
```

Or you can build convert map for it:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase


convert_dict = {
    c: ascii_lowercase[(ascii_lowercase.index(c) + 3) % len(ascii_lowercase)]
    for c in ascii_lowercase
}


def encode(original_text: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(
        convert_dict[c]
        if c in convert_dict else c
        for c in original_text
    )


print(encode('test xyz'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a `list`, to iterate over the characters of a string.
So I think you need something like this:

```
cipher = 3 # You could use a different cipher value
message = 'This is an example of Caesars Cipher!'
encrypted = ''.join(chr(ord(char) + cipher) for char in message)
decrypted = ''.join(chr(ord(char) - cipher) for char in encrypted)
print(encrypted)
print(decrypted)
```

This code outputs:

```
Wklv#lv#dq#h{dpsoh#ri#Fdhvduv#Flskhu$
This is an example of Caesars Cipher!
```